# Cart Total no longer working on DevDemon forms for EE2

Tags: forms, devdemon, devdemon-forms

We just updated a client to EE2.11.6 and DevDemon Forms 3.5.3, and they're seeing issues with the product total no longer working. Before, you would add a product field and a total field. When you added or removed items, the total updated automatically. But this stopped working after the update.

Is there a script that is required in later iterations of Forms to get the total working?

Comment: Any jQuery Error in console log?